# ROC Curve plot: Cannot display my x-axis and y-axis correctly

Tags: python, scikit-learn, roc

I got some issues with displaying the x-axis and y-axis.
The fpr and tpr are received from the sklearn package roc_curve, e.g `fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(...)`.

This is my code to plot the ROC-Curve:

```
from sklearn.metrics import RocCurveDisplay
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
# display = RocCurveDisplay(fpr=mi_scores['fpr'].sort_values(), tpr=mi_scores['tpr'].sort_values()).plot(ax)
plt.plot(mi_scores['fpr'].sort_values(), 
             mi_scores['tpr'].sort_values())
plt.xlabel("Flase Positive Rate")
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1],'r--')
plt.show()
```

But it displays like this:
[image]

While I would expect it to display the normal scale + x-axis/y-axis. (e.g. 0.1, 0.2 ... 1)